# text on wide-enough rightarrow

Tags: arrows

Is there a way to resize the rightarrow so that it can adjust to the width of the text over it?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \overset{\text{l'Hopital's rule}}{\Longrightarrow}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The code above only generates result like this, which is non-adjusted.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\xRightarrow` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \xRightarrow{\text{l'Hopital's rule}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It has the syntax: `\xRightarrow[below]{above}`